# Build failed: Build error details not available when deploying a Python Google Cloud Function with a local package

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function that processes messages from a queue. When I put all the modules in the root of the function (where `main.py` and `requirements.txt` live) everything works fine. If I move the modules into a local package as shown [here in the docs.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#structuring_source_code), then when I deploy the function by uploading the Zip file using the cloud console I get an error saying `Build failed: Build error details not available` with no other info.

```
.
├── main.py
├── module_one.py
├── module_two.py
└── requirements.txt
```

at the root of the archive I upload works just fine.

```
.
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── local_package_one/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_one.py
└── local_package_two/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module_two.py
```

earns me `Build failed: Build error details not available`. In the second configuration, I update all the affected `import` statements. I initially suspected the `requirements.txt` file since it isn't shown in the example, but [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) they state that it should work just fine. The example there also shows a top-level folder named after the function, so I tried putting that at the root of the archive with everything inside of it and got the same results.

I changed the imports from

```
from module_one import MyClass
```

to

```
from local_package_one.module_one import MyClass
```

Comment: Can you include more details? What do your updated imports look like?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify the import changes.

Comment: What happens if you try calling your function locally?

Comment: I have to admit I'm not sure how to run the whole shebang locally. I have the PubSub emulator running locally and can publish to the topic that the function should listen to. I can also start my function with the functions-framework like `functions-framework --target myFunction` from the same directory as the `main.py` and it starts up and listens without any errors. I'm working on either linking the function to Pub/Sub or what the request needs to look like imitate one with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a number of issues, but without more details it's hard to say.

This general pattern works though, e.g.:

```
$ tree
.
├── local_package_one
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_one.py
├── local_package_two
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_two.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt

$ cat main.py
from local_package_one.module_one import hello
from local_package_two.module_two import world

def test(request):
    return hello + ' ' + world

$ cat local_package_one/module_one.py
hello = "hello"

$ cat local_package_two/module_two.py
world = "world"

$ gcloud functions deploy test --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.

$ curl https://<my-function>.cloudfunctions.net/test
hello world%
```

Comment: Thanks, that's both helpful and frustrating. Helpful because it looks like I'm doing things right but frustrating because mine still isn't working. I'll try your minimal example in a bit so I can be really sure I'm actually doing things right.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting somewhere now. I can deploy the function from the command line the way you did here, but if I deploy it from the console it breaks. I suspect a character encoding issue because the `requirements.txt` published from the console has lots of weird symbols but the one published from the CLI is fine. This also happens when I don't use local packages but doesn't cause an error for some reason so I'm not 100% sure that's the cause.

Comment: Intersting, by "console" do you mean Cloud Shell? Or in the GCF console editor? What are the "weird symbols"? Would be interested to see the different `requirements.txt` files if you can include them in your question. This might be a bug.

Comment: By console I meant the web site https://console.cloud.google.com/functions and then using that interface to upload a ZIP file. I just tried to reproduce it and I'm still getting the same error but the `requirements.txt` file is just fine now, so that wasn't it after all.  I appreciate you looking into it, being able to deploy from the CLI is just fine for me now. If you're agreeable to it I'll mark this as the answer since it taught me a workaround using the CLI.

Comment: But if you want to keep digging I'm happy to do what I can to help nail it down!

Comment: Sounds good! If it happens again feel free to reach out: dustiningram@google.com